# Principal curvature at a given point

Tags: differential-geometry

Compute the principal curvature of the surface$$\frac {x^2}{p}+\frac {y^2}{q}=2z $$ at the point $M(0,0,0)$

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: The principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of the matrix of second fundamental forms. Does that help get you started?

Comment: @Cocomos The point where I am confuse is how can I find the eigenvalue of the matrix of second fundamental form?

Comment: @Cocomos: That's not correct (unless the first fundamental form is the identity at the point).

Comment: Use a parametrisation to calculate the second fundamental form at the origin and observe that a unit normal vector at this point is given by e.g. $e_3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following geometric observation should help you to answer your question without long calculations.

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth\regular surface, $p\in S$ and a unit speed curve $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to S$ with $c(0)=p$ and $c'(0)=v.$ Then $$\langle c''(0),\nu(p)\rangle=II_p(v,v),$$
where $\nu:S\to S^2$ is the gauss map and $II_p$ the second fundamental form. This implies the following geometric interpretation of the principal curvatures:

For $v\in T_pS$ let $V$ denote the plane going through $p$ and including $v,\nu(p)$ (vectors attached to $p$). Then consider $S\cap V.$ This can be parametrized by a unit speed curve $c_v.$ Let $\kappa_v(p)$ denote the curvature (with respect to the given unit normal vector) of the curve $c_v$ at the point $p.$ Then the principal curvatures are 
$$\kappa_1(p)=\min_{v\in T_pM}\kappa_v(p)\text{ and } \kappa_2(p)=\max_{v\in T_pM}\kappa_v(p).$$

So in order to solve your problem try to imagine the surface and make yourself clear that the tangent plane to the origin is the xy-plane and that as a unit normal vector you can choose $\nu(p)=(0,0,1).$ When you intersect your surface with a plane through the origin and the z-axis, you get a smooth curve. The principal curvatures are the minimal and maximal curvatures of all curves obtained by intersecting your surface with such a plane.

Comment: It is too complicated for me to understand.... Can you please explain it in a bit more simple way?

Comment: I added a less formal description.

Comment: Can you give me a working rule ?

Comment: A working rule would be to choose a parametrisation and determine the first $g_{ij}$ an second fundamentalform $h_{ij}$ and then determine the eigenvalues of $(h_{ij})(g^{ij})$. However in this nice set up you can do it by drawing pictures and using the explanation\intuition I gave above. And don't forget this is math, so if you don't get something from the beginning try to think about it and think about a respond you get and don't just say you don't understand it (especially in a field with "geometry" in its name it will be good to draw pictures!)

Comment: Ok. The parameterization which I found was: $x=\sqrt{2pu}\cos v, \ \ y=\sqrt{2qu} \sin v, \ \ z=u$ But my friend said that it is not a good parametrization. So can you suggest me one ?

Comment: I'd stick to pictures! Do what I explained ath the bottom of my answer.